# What are the differences between ok(), successful() and failed() in Laravels guzzlehttp/guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

What are the differences between these three Guzzle (`guzzlehttp/guzzle`) methods:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('http://example.com');
```

1. $response->**ok()** : bool;
2. $response->**successful()** : bool;
3. $response->**failed()** : bool;

And when does it make sense to use one of these methods in preference to the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SOmeone else just asked a very similiar question to this, but this time is asked better and with more context :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly So was I. And I tried to ask my question more precisely. I hope I have learned something ;-)

Comment: Show me this function $response->successful() in guzzle documentation  :)

Comment: @WiatroBosy sure. Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests. And i updated my answear, to keep confusion to a minimum.

Comment: not in laravel doc - bat in guzzle doc pls. You write "What are the differences between ok(), successful() and failed() in Guzzle?"

Comment: @WiatroBosy i mean the methods from this  `guzzlehttp/guzzle` lib. i updated my title. thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods come from Laravel

> public function successful() {    return $this->status() >= 200 &&
> $this->status() < 300; }
>
> public function ok() {   return $this->status() === 200; }
>
> public function failed() {   return $this->serverError() ||
> $this->clientError(); }

and the differences can be seen with the naked eye

successful() -return true when staus is bettwen 200 , 300

ok() - return true only when status = 200

failed() - return bool if any error

> And when does it make sense to use one of these methods in preference
> to the other?
> It depends on the code and the need